# Facing problem while deploying crowdsale smart contract,

Tags: solidity, remix

this is my code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

import "token2.sol";

contract crowdsale{

     Token public mytoken; // token being sold

      address payable public wallet;  // whre funds are located;

      uint public rate; // how many token unit a buyer gets per wei
      uint public weiraised; // amount of weiraised

       event token_purchased(address indexed purchaser, address indexed benefeciary, uint value, uint amount);

       constructor(uint _rate, address payable _wallet, Token  _token) public{
         require(_rate > 0);
         require(_wallet != address(0));
       //  require(_token != address(0));
          rate = _rate;
          wallet = _wallet;
          mytoken = _token;

       }
       function buytokens(address _beneficiary) public payable{
            uint wei_amount = msg.value;
            _prevalidate_purchase(_beneficiary, wei_amount);

            // calculate Token amount to be created 

            uint tokens = _gettokenamount(wei_amount);

            // update state;

            weiraised = weiraised + wei_amount;

            _processpurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);
            emit token_purchased(msg.sender, _beneficiary, wei_amount, tokens);
            _forwardfunds();

       }

       function () external payable{
           buytokens(msg.sender);
       }

       function _prevalidate_purchase(address _beneficiary, uint wei_amount) internal  {
           require(_beneficiary != address(0));
           require(wei_amount != 0);
       }


       function _delivertokens(address _beneficiary, uint _tokenamount) internal{
           mytoken.transfer(_beneficiary, _tokenamount);
       }

       function  _processpurchase(address _beneficiary, uint _tokenamount) internal{
           _delivertokens(_beneficiary, _tokenamount);
       }




       function _gettokenamount(uint wei_amount) internal view returns(uint){
           return wei_amount * rate;
       }

       function _forwardfunds() internal {


            wallet.transfer(msg.value);

       }


}
```

this is the error i get:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below).
The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always failing transaction
```

Comment: Attach the content of token2.sol also, we cannot see where is the issue with that one missing.

Answer (score 1):

This deployment can revert for only two reasons:

1. `require(_rate > 0);`
2. `require(_wallet != address(0));`

Make sure that you pass a non-zero rate and a non-zero wallet.

Comment: i have tried this , but after deploying when i run "buytoken" function it show  same error

Comment: @mukesh: The title of your question says "Facing problem while deploying"! If you have a different problem at this point, then please post it as a separate question.